# Scala: ExecutionContext for future for-comprehension

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension, executioncontext

When I make a `future`, or apply methods like `onSuccess` and `map`, I can specify ExecutionContext for them.

For example,

```scala
val f = future {
  // code
} executionContext

f.map(someFunction)(executionContext)

f onSuccess {
  // code
} executionContext
```

However, if I use a for-comprehension of future, how can I specify ExecutionContext for the `yield` part?

```scala
for {
  f <- future1
  g <- future2
} yield {
  // code to be executed after future1 onSuccess and future2 onSuccess
  // What ExecutionContext runs this code?
} // (executionContext) here does not work
```

And, what ExecutionContext runs the code in yield if not specified?

---

**EDIT**

OK. Thanks to answers, I found something.
If I don't define or import ***implicit* ExecutionContext** (like `Implicits.global`),
the for-comprehension does not compile. That means, for-comprehension uses implicit ExecutionContext.

Then, how can I use for-comprehension without implicit ExecutionContext, i.e. how to specify?

Comment: See my answer for the underlying reason of why the `for` comprehensions won't compile if you don't have an `implicit` specified.

Comment: @flavian In simple situation, that works. But if there are two ExecutionContext to use for for-comprehension, how can I specify? It will show errors like `ambiguous implicit values`. I can block each time I define or import implicit vals or defs & for-comprehension, but is there another way?

Comment: just to be absolutely sure - do you mean a single `for`-comprehension with multiple generators (in which case flavian's answer works) or multiple consequent `for`-comprehensions?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato I meant a single for-comprehension with multiple generators. The solution was not that simple, but Scala doesn't seem to support explicit ExecutionContext for for-comprehension...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ExecutionContext` parameter is actually `implicit`. That means you can:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

implicit val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(//etc)
for {
  f <- future1
  g <- future2
} yield {
  // code to be executed after future1 onSuccess and future2 onSuccess
  // What ExecutionContext runs this code?: the one above.
}
```

You also have a default, namely `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`.
This has as many threads as the processors on the running machine.

It won't be used by all Futures by default, you still have to import it.

**Update**: If you really want to specifiy, although it's not recommended, you can unwrap the `for yield`

```
val combined = futureA.flatMap(x => futureB)(context)
```

Comment: What if there are two implicit ExecutionContexts in scope and you need to select one?

Comment: @kostya you can use selective aliasing like this: `import com.bla.bla.{ contextToDiscard => _, _ }`. This will import just one of them into scope if it's a package import causing the problems. Another way is to move imports that bring in the executors to a lower scope.

Answer (score 1):

Since `for` comprehensions are "mapped" to `map`/`flatMap` operations, and the `ExecutionContext` parameters of those are implicit, I guess you can try to add an `implicit val` in the local scope:

`implicit val myContext:ExecutionContext = ...`

.

I don't believe there is a "default" implicit `ExecutionContext`, but the most commonly used one is [`ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%24%24Implicits%24) .