# How can I pass execution context in for comprehension whithout using implicit in scala?

Tags: scala, future

I have a code which is using for-comprehension to run database query :

```
val totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB = Future(/..Doing db job../)(executionContext)
val listOfRestrictedFundFromDB = Future(/..Doing db job../)(executionContext)

val res = for {
      totalFeeNoticeAmount <- totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB
      listOfRestrictedFund <- listOfRestrictedFundFromDB
    } yield (totalFeeNoticeAmount, listOfRestrictedFund)
```

We know for running for-comprehension we need to pass implicit execution context.
But in this case I am wanting to pass execution context manually.
What is the way ?

**Edited:**

```
val res = for {
          totalFeeNoticeAmount <-(?:ExecutionContext) totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB
          listOfRestrictedFund <-(?:ExecutionContext) listOfRestrictedFundFromDB
        } yield (totalFeeNoticeAmount, listOfRestrictedFund)
```

`totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB` and `listOfRestrictedFundFromDB` are both Future type already initiated.

Is there any way of passing here
`<-(?:ExecutionContext)` ?

Comment: Any implicit argument can be passed explicitly as a plain argument, but if there are multiple implicit arguments for the same call, then all these arguments must be passed explicitly.

Comment: @cchantep,  I know that.  I edited my question. Actually I am wanting to pass execution context  in this `<-(?:ExecutionContext)` part explicitly.

Comment: I believe the simplest way would be to create a new block or function for that part and set a new implicit execution context for that block.

Comment: Other simple alternative, given your futures do not depend on each other would be to create them with the explicit EC you want and then compose them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the simplest solution to this problem is just to create an auxiliary function.

```
def foo(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[(Int, Int)] = {
  val totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB = Future(/..Doing db job../)
  val listOfRestrictedFundFromDB = Future(/..Doing db job../)

  for {
    totalFeeNoticeAmount <- totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB
    listOfRestrictedFund <- listOfRestrictedFundFromDB
  } yield (totalFeeNoticeAmount, listOfRestrictedFund)
}
```

That way when you need it you can just call it like this: `foo(ec = myExplicitExecutionContext)`

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps consider [scala-async](https://github.com/scala/scala-async) which has gained [experimental compiler support](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.3) `-Xasync` in Scala 2.13.3 where the following for-comprehension

```
for {
  a <- Future(41)
  b <- Future(1)
} yield {
  a + b
}
```

can be rewritten as

```
async {
  val a = async(41)(ec)
  val b = async(1)(ec)
  await(a) + await(b)
}(ec)
```

where we can pass in execution context `ec` explicitly without resorting to flatMap/map.

Another hacky option could be [better-monadic-for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for#define-implicits-in-for-comprehensions-or-matches) which supports defining implicits inside for-comprehensions

```
val ec: ExecutionContext = ???
(for {
  implicit0(ec: ExecutionContext) <- Future.successful(ec)
  a <- Future(41)(ec)
  b <- Future(1)(ec)
} yield {
  a + b
})(ec)
```

Comment: `for {
  a <-(?:ExecutionContex)  Future(41)(ec)
  b <-(?:ExecutionContex) Future(1)(ec)
} yield {
  a + b
}`  I want to pass in this `<-(?:ExecutionContex)`

Comment: in that case I will need "scala-async" lib. I am up-voting you. But is there any way in  `for-comprehension` ?

Comment: @MHJ I believe not, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21256762/5205022

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite

```
val res = for {
  totalFeeNoticeAmount <- totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB
  listOfRestrictedFund <- listOfRestrictedFundFromDB
} yield (totalFeeNoticeAmount, listOfRestrictedFund)
```

as

```
val res = totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB.flatMap(totalFeeNoticeAmount =>
  listOfRestrictedFundFromDB.map(listOfRestrictedFund =>
    (totalFeeNoticeAmount, listOfRestrictedFund)
  )
)
```

For example if `totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB` and `listOfRestrictedFundFromDB` are `Future`s then you can pass implicit `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` explicitly

```
val res = totalFeeNoticeAmountFromDB.flatMap(totalFeeNoticeAmount =>
  listOfRestrictedFundFromDB.map(listOfRestrictedFund =>
    (totalFeeNoticeAmount, listOfRestrictedFund)
  )(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)
)(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)
```

Comment: @MHJ for comprension is is always sequential not parallel.

Comment: @MHJ no it doesn't matter if it relies in the previous or not. It is always sequential because for comprehension is just sugar syntax for `flatMap` so it is the same code. You can make it run like in parallel if you define the futures before before the `for`, because futures are eager they will be running before sequencing them, but that is actually a bug and not a feature. Anyways, you can do exactly the same with `flatMap`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, yes you are right. Thing is if we initiate the future before we call in for-comprehension ,  parallel things happens before coming to for-comprehension

Comment: @MHJ yes and I am telling you you can do exactly the same using `flatMap` so that should solve your problem.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, yes by flatMap I can solve that way and in parallel if I initiate the futures before come to flatMap. My problem was using explicit `executionContext in <-(?:ExecutionContext)`

Comment: @MHJ ok so let me put this simple. There is no way to pass explicitly the execution context used in a **Future** `for comprehension` period. You have a couple of alternatives: 1. Using `flatMap` instead so you can define the ec used in all operations. - 2. Encapsulate all this on it own function, so you can pass the EC for the whole function.

Comment: @MHJ Well, you can create your own compiler plugin (like "better-monadic-for" plugin mentioned by **Mario Galic** in his answer) that will expand `for { a <-(ec) fa; b <-(ec1) fb } yield (a, b)` into `fa.flatMap(a => fb.map(b => (a, b))(ec))(ec1)` but this would be an overkill. Such plugin will need to modify `parser` phase as well because `for { a <-(ec) fa...` isn't parsable now ("better-monadic-for" doesn't modify `parser`).